# why isn't this simple node program printing contents of current directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a folder with a few `js` files in it:

```
admin$ ls

filterfiles.js  filterfiles.js~ program.js  program.js~
```

program.js is a node program with the following contents:

```
var dir = process.argv[2]

var fs = require('fs')
fs.readdir(dir, function(results){console.log(results)})
```

When I do the following, why do I get null, instead of a list of the files in the directory?

```
admin$ node program.js './' 
null
```

Comment: @Icepickle  Actually I misprinted this on a second try.  I have the same problem with ./

Comment: @Icepickle  just edited it to show

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first argument of the callback for `fs.readdir` is the error, the result is in argument 2. This is standard practice for node callbacks.

You want:

```
fs.readdir(dir, function(err,results){console.log(results)})
```